# Why is onItemClick from gridView not working correctly?

Tags: java, android, gridview, click

I am doing a small quiz game with a custom adapter and a gridview.

For some reason when a click on a gridView's item is performed, the view, the position and the id return 0 or null.

The app crashes when tries to set the item's background color.

---

The Logcat links me to these 2 lines:

```
gridRespuestas.performItemClick(gridRespuestas.getChildAt(0), 0, gridRespuestas.getItemIdAtPosition(0));
```

&

```
LinearLayout respuesta = (LinearLayout) view;
respuesta.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5e3535"));
```

---

Here it's the ridView's listener:

```
 gridRespuestas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                contador.cancel();

                gridRespuestas.setEnabled(false);
                LinearLayout respuesta = (LinearLayout) view;

                // Si la respuesta seleccionada es correcta
                boolean repuestaCorrecta = preguntasFiltradas.get(preguntaMostrada).getRespuestas().get(position).isEsCorrecta();

                if(repuestaCorrecta ){

                    // Pone el fondo de la respuesta en verde
                    respuesta.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#355e4e"));
                }
                // Si es incorrecta
                else{
                    // Pone el fondo de la respuesta pulsada en rojo
                    respuesta.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5e3535"));

                    // Por cada view dentro de la gridview
                    GridView grid = (GridView) parent;
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < grid.getChildCount() ; i++){

                        // Coge cada elemento dentro de parent > LinearLayour > Textview
                        TextView text = (TextView)((LinearLayout)grid.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(0);

                        // Si la pregunta es correcta
                        if(preguntasFiltradas.get(preguntaMostrada).getRespuestas().get(i).isEsCorrecta()){

                            // Cambia el fondo de color verde
                            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#355e4e"));
                        }
                    }
                }

                juego(position , juegoLayout, gridRespuestas, contador);

            }
        });
```

---

The adapter:

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {


    private List<Respuesta> respuestas;
    private Activity context;

    public Adaptador(Activity _context,List<Respuesta> _respuestas) {

        context = _context;
        respuestas = _respuestas;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.place_respuesta, null);
        }

        final TextView respuesta = view.findViewById(R.id.placeRespuesta);
        respuesta.setText(respuestas.get(position).getRespuesta());

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int retorno = 0;

        if(respuestas != null)
            retorno = respuestas.size();

        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }


}
```

---

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.LinearLayout.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.joc.Juego$3.onItemClick(Juego.java:136)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
        at com.example.joc.Juego$1.onFinish(Juego.java:82)
```

---

EDIT: I include the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/grisOscuro"
    android:id="@+id/juegoLayout">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/joc"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/inicio"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/home" />

    //Textview para las preguntas
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pregunta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Blanco"
        android:layout_marginTop="365dp"/>

    //GridView para las respuestas
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridRespuestas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="780dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tiempo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="150sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="30"
        android:textColor="@color/Blanco"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you define gridRespuestas properly?  could you show where you did that?

Comment: @Coder123
`final GridView gridRespuestas = findViewById(R.id.gridRespuestas); 
Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(this, respuestas);
gridRespuestas.setAdapter(adaptador);`

Comment: try to cast it like so, GridView gridRespuestas = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridRespuestas);  also can you post the relevant xml part of the gridRespuestas?

Comment: I edited the post. I forgot to say that this happens sometimes, looks like random

Comment: remove the caps from the id.. rename it to grid_respuestas and try agai, upperCase letters are not allowed.. I don't know how I didnt realize before

Comment: with `final GridView gridrespuestas = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridRespuestas);` keeps crashing: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.LinearLayout.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: yeah.. see my comment below

Comment: I tried that on the first place but my gridviews's onItemClickListener didn't seem to work when a OnClick is inside the getView's adapter

Comment: But I need to set the background when user clicks into an item, if the answer is incorrect that item should be red and the right answer should be green. Could you please show how would you do that without OnClick?

Comment: also in your adapter you pass respuestas and not gridRespuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I just surrounded everything inside the OnItemClickListener with

```
if (view != null){
// Code to execute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your id:

```
   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_respuestas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="780dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

since upper case letters are not allowed in the Android xml files

Comment: check that you don't have more uppercase variablres in your xml